# Hydration enthalpy of cations

Tags: ions, enthalpy

Can someone provide reliable data on the solvation / hydration enthalpies of $\ce{Ti^{4+}}$ and $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ ions, or explain which is more stable qualitatively? According to this article<sup>1</sup>

CFSE in $\ce{Cr^{3+}}$ is around 59.7 kcal = 249.7848 kJ

and according to the abstract of an article by Uudsemaa and Tamm,<sup>2</sup> the estimated hydration energy of $\ce{Ti^{4+}}$ is around 7800 kJ/mol

Is this data correct? can someone explain qualitatively as well?

### References

(1) http://hydration%20energy%20of%20Cr3+%20value

(2) Uudsema, M.; Tamm, T. Calculations of hydrated titanium ion complexes: structure and influence of the first two coordination spheres. *Chem. Phys. Lett.* **2001,** *342* (5–6), 667–672. [DOI: 10.1016/S0009-2614(01)00617-0](http://doi.org/10.1016/S0009-2614(01)00617-0).

Comment: Your first link is broken. Anyway CFSE is merely one small contribution to hydration enthalpy (which are ion-dipole interactions). You also need to explain very clearly what you mean by "stability", because that is not a very clear-cut concept.

Comment: Logically one would expect the hydration enthalpy of Ti(4+) (smaller, more highly charged cation) to be much more exothermic than that of Cr(3+). However there's a reason why it's an "estimated" hydration energy and there's a reason why it's a computational study. Ti(4+) doesn't exist in water, probably not even as an aquo complex. The paper writes "The Ti(4+) cations have too large charge to be stable as simple hydrates, and usually exist in hydrolysed forms, e.g. [Ti(OH)2](2+) or [Ti(OH)3]+." Reference given is Holleman-Wiberg.

Comment: In order to help you out on this question, it would be good if [you could include human readable citations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3529/4945) in your post.

Comment: More the charge density more the hydration energy...You can find the stability this way...